# How do I evaluate a helper in Jade without outputting its result?

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a Jade template that needs to call a helper, but not display its output:

```
// views/foo.html.jade:
p
  Some content...
#{ someHelperSetterMethod('bar'); }
```

Unfortunately, since `someHelperSetterMethod` returns nothing, I get "undefined" output in my template. Is there a way to do non-outputting evaluation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p
  some content
- someHelperSetterMethod('bar')
```